# Find DAO Record

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, dao, recordset

Is it possible to use DoCmd.GoToRecord or DoCmd.FindRecord in order to quickly find a record in a table, edit the record and get the focus on that record (I want to start looping from that record later)?

I believe such method (if applicable) would be faster than looping through the entire recordset (especially with a large recordset).

Assuming the Primary key is 9999 (Fields(0) = 9999), I have tried:

```
Dim rs as DAO.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Tbltest")
DoCmd.FindRecord "9999", acEntire, True, acSearchAll, True
Debug.Print rs.Fields(0)
```

I get "1"; the method failed.

Comment: This code finds the value "9999" in the field in focus of the form in focus. `rs.Fields(0)` still points to the first record, that is the '1' you get.

Answer (score 3):

With a `DAO.Recordset`, you use the [`rs.FindFirst` and `rs.FindNext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194099.aspx) methods.

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Tbltest", dbOpenDynaset)
lngValue = 9999
rs.FindFirst "myPrimaryKey = " & lngValue

' start loop from there
If Not rs.NoMatch Then
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        Debug.Print rs(0)
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```

If it's a local table, there is also the [`rs.Seek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836416.aspx) method, but if there is a chance that the table will some day be linked from a backend or server database, I suggest sticking with the Find methods.